# Error : realloc(): invalid pointer

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

I want to realloc a `char**` inside a `struct MotInfo**`, it is a struct created by me. But I have an error when I try my `realloc`:

```
    int x;
    MotInfo** hashtable = malloc(TAILLE*sizeof(struct MotInfo*));
    for(x=0; x<TAILLE;x++)
    {
        hashtable[x] = NULL;
    }
    struct MotInfo* mot_info;
    int i;
    hashtable[5] = malloc(sizeof(struct MotInfo*));

    mot_info = malloc(sizeof(struct MotInfo*));
    mot_info->mot = "manger"; 

    mot_info->urls = malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
    mot_info->occurrences = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    mot_info->taille = 2;
    for(i = 0;i<2;i++)
    {
        mot_info->urls[i] = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions";
        mot_info->occurrences[i] = 3;
    }
    printf("OK\n");
    hashtable[5] = mot_info;
    hashtable[5]->urls = realloc(hashtable[5]->urls, sizeof(char*)*2);
```

I have localised my error in the last line, but I have this error :

```
realloc(): invalid pointer:
```

Comment: `hashtable[5]->urls` contains some garbage value instead of a pointer previously returned by `malloc` or `realloc`, or NULL.

Comment: Provide the structure definition of `MotInfo`

Comment: @lurker `mot_info->urls = malloc(...)` followed by `hashtable[5] = mot_info`.

Comment: You have a memory leak. First you set `hashtable[5] = malloc(...)` then you do `hashtable[5] = mot_info` but you don't free the old memory.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, missed that...

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) when calling `realloc()`, always assign to a 'temp' variable, then check (!=NULL)  and IF not NULL, then assign to the target variable.  Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the original heap memory pointer is lost, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: it is not defined within the scope of the posted code, however, the macro `TAILLE` must be 6 or greater.

Answer (score 4):

```
struct MotInfo* mot_info;
mot_info = malloc(sizeof(struct MotInfo*));
```

`mot_info` is a pointer to `struct MotInfo`, but the space you allocate is only enough to hold a pointer, not the struct (which is likely to be bigger since it has at least four members). When you overstep the allocation, you may stomp on malloc`s bookkeeping.

```
hashtable[5] = malloc(sizeof(struct MotInfo*));       // (a)
mot_info = malloc(sizeof(struct MotInfo*));
hashtable[5] = mot_info;                              // (b)
```

That assigment on (b) loses the pointer to the block allocated at (a).

```
mot_info->urls = malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
hashtable[5] = mot_info;
hashtable[5]->urls = realloc(hashtable[5]->urls, sizeof(char*)*2);
```

I don't understand this either, aren't you `realloc`ing to the same size?

Even if not, you probably shouldn't assign the return value of `realloc` to the same pointer immediately: it loses the pointer to the memory block if `realloc` fails.

Comment: I just replicated the same error that I have in a bigger code, but I want my hashtable[5]->urls to be bigger, this is why I use realloc, I want more space for my urls

Answer (score 0):

You did `hashtable[5] = malloc(sizeof(struct MotInfo*))` but `hashtable[5]` is itself a pointer to `struct MotInfo`, so you probably would do `hashtable[5] = malloc(sizeof(struct MotInfo))`

Comment: "deferenciated" isn't a word.